# Ubuntu 18.04.2 Software Boutique

Tags: software-boutique

When Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS was installed, the Software Boutique program was better responsive to my requests. Now, whether I want to use it to install or uninstall something, the program answered: "You are not allowed to perform this action. You do not have the required privileges to perform this action." That results in my using some other complicated ways, problems, etc.
So, are there some preventing actions on my part for the future?

Answer (score 0):

Check the rights to your **snap** folder, they should be at least **755**

```
sudo chmod 755 /home/[YOUR USERNAME HERE]
```

I've had the same problem and this worked for me.

Comment: Well, I tried and that didn't work. Possibly, some problems with the system. "A problem" was reported by PC already twice. Thanks anyway.

Comment: And, in the "shap" folder I have "ubuntu-welcome" folder, which has 3 empty folders, one of the marked "335."